# SailsJS How to apply sort by on an instance method and instance method which is populated from another model?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Hi consider this example

```
//        surname_and_name: function(){
//            return (this.name_last==null ? '' : this.name_last + ' ') +
//                (this.name_middle==null ? '': this.name_middle + ' ') +
//                (this.name_first==null ? '' : this.name_first + ' ')  +
//                (this.name_prefix==null ? '' : this.name_prefix + ' ') +
//                (this.name_suffix==null ? '' : this.name_suffix);
//        },

     toJSON: function() {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        obj.surname_and_name = (obj.name_last==null ? '' : obj.name_last + ' ') +
            (obj.name_middle==null ? '': obj.name_middle + ' ') +
            (obj.name_first==null ? '' : obj.name_first + ' ')  +
            (obj.name_prefix==null ? '' : obj.name_prefix + ' ') +
            (obj.name_suffix==null ? '' : obj.name_suffix);
       return obj;
    }
```

i am trying to query and sort it by "surname_and_name" computed field.
i tried commented code as well, i get this error, for method

```
co_user.find(sort : {surname_and_name: 'asc' }).exec(error,res) 

Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'co_user.surname_and_name' in 'order clause'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toJSON` method is called when sending model data back from the server, not during queries.  Therefore, the `surname_and_name` property is not available during queries; only real model attributes can be used as query parameters.  If this kind of sort is important to you, I'd recommend making an actual `surname_and_name` attribute for your model which gets automatically calculated every time the model is saved, using the model class's `afterCreate()` and `afterUpdate()` [lifecycle callbacks](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models/Lifecyclecallbacks.html).